# Create executable jar from JUNIT 5 without maven/gradle

Tags: junit, jar, junit5

How do I create an executable jar for my JUnit 5 test class without maven/gradle/etc.?

If I try Eclipse Junit Class -> Export -> Java -> Runnable Jar the jar file produced will not run, it says main method is needed. However, the testRunner examples I've found online are all for JUnit4 and have compatibility issues with JUnit 5.

Comment: Why do you want to create an executable for your test classes? Usually, a test class is intended for development purposes and is only used after compilation to ensure correct functionality. If you could provide a couple more details, we might be able to understand what you're trying to do, bc packaging your test classes into an executable jar sounds like something you shouldn't really do.

Comment: I am packaging it in order for it to be run on any platform without the need to pull the whole project.

Comment: But why do you want to run the test cases in first place? Like I said before, a test case is designed to be run during development, and during development you should have the entire project available, anyway.

Comment: For school project executable jar is requirement so that there are no issues when running tests to see accuracy. We did not absolutely need to make jUnit tests but I thought it would be nicer. Typical tests are easy to make an executable jar with but I am finding it difficult with jUnit 5.

Comment: So you need a runnable jar for your **project**, not for your **test cases**. Test cases should not be shipped with the final product, since they add no functionality to the final product.

Comment: No I actually need a runnable jar for the test cases for right now. The project is in stages, we must submit runnable jar for test cases. Currently the method that is being used is to create a very simple testing structure completely in main method.